# Where can I find Foursquare Datasets?

Tags: gps, foursquare-data

I'm doing research which aims to analyse location based social networks. So the Foursquare dataset is suitable for me. Is there any Foursquare dataset available? I need 4 information in the dataset: userID (number is ok); position(long,lat); time; relationship between user.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I guess its not possible (check this link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/foursquare-api/FNF09OSg8dA/EX0420Ja6zEJ) but researching on this

Answer (score 1):

FourSquare API has this information - but is limited on the number of requests
https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/ratelimits

For full documentaion
https://developer.foursquare.com/

Community Group has moved to StackExchange
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foursquare